# Swapping Two Numbers, but only in a special case

Tags: javascript

I guess we all know about destructuring to swap two variables `a` and `b`, namely: `[a, b] = [b, a]` and other clever ways like `a = b + (b = a, 0)`. However, I have a different situation which I feel should have a simple answer.

I have a variable `a` that can be one of `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6`. If it is `a===3` then I want `a` to reassign to `4`. If `a===4` then I want `a` to reassign to `3`. **BUT** if `a` is any of the other values, I want it to remain the same.

So is there a clever, 1 line bit of code that can do this? For completeness, I want a short version of this:

```
switch(a){
    case 3: a = 4; break;
    case 4: a = 3; break;
    // default: a = a; break; // Hashed out, because it is not needed
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take an object for swapping the values and the value directly as default value, like

```
a = { 3: 4, 4: 3 }[a] || a;
```

If you like to work with a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, like zero, you could take the [Nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) instead of [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR).

```
a = { 3: 4, 4: 3 }[a] ?? a;
```

Comment: I wish I could mark 2 answers, because I like this and epascarello's answers the best.

Answer (score 2):

Using a Computed Property Name

```js
function test(a) {
  a = { [a]: a, 3: 4, 4: 3 }[a]; 
  return a;
}


[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach(n =>console.log(n, test(n)));
```

Comment: I wish I could mark 2 answers, because I like this and Nina's answers the best.

Answer (score 1):

You could use nested ternary operators, but I think your current switch code is easier to understand:

```
a = a === 3 ? 4 : a === 4 ? 3 : a;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array and get the index of the item at `a`, then use the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to check whether the value is falsy:

```js
let a = 3
a = [,,,4,3][a] ?? a
console.log(a)
```

Comment: This would win at code golf as long as there is not bigger numbers.